# Javascript String to Object/Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript string which looks like this:

```
['Chris','Johannes','test','lag@a.deaaas','lag@a.deaaa','lag@a.eaaa','lag@a.ea']
```

I want to pass this to a php document as an array/object. What is the easiest (jQuery?) way to  do this?

Edit: I grab this string from the DOM:

```
<div class="container" data-users="['Chris','Johannes','test','lag@a.deaaas','lag@a.deaaa','lag@a.eaaa','lag@a.ea']" data-userids="[1,2,3,12,13,15,16]">
```

Comment: Use a proper [JSON string](http://json.org/) and `JSON.parse`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, convert the `data-users` and `data-userids` into JSON (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). That means the all quotes must be double quotes (`""`).

```
<div class="container" data-users='["Chris","Johannes","test","lag@a.deaaas","lag@a.deaaa","lag@a.eaaa","lag@a.ea"]' data-userids='[1,2,3,12,13,15,16]'>
```

Then you can get the data like this:

```
var dataUsers = JSON.parse($('div.container').attr('data-users'))
// dataUsers[0], dataUsers[1], dataUsers.length ....
var dataUserIds = JSON.parse($('div.container').attr('data-userids'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function, which will automatically cast values to the correct javascript datatype, including arrays and objects:

```
var container = $('.container');
var users = container.data('users');
var userIds = container.data('userids');
```